# Android - Make own directory for saving Image taken by camera

Tags: android, directory, android-camera, mkdir

I have searching how to make my own folder for saving picture taken by camera. and give a auto name taken by time. In my code i make it to save on sdcard0 directory. but the name always same. can someone tell me how to do it.

Here my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private EditText nama, harga, kondisi, notelepon;

private TextView messageText;
private Button uploadButton, btnselectpic;
private ImageView imageview;
private int serverResponseCode = 0;
private ProgressDialog dialog = null;

private String upLoadServerUri = null;
private String imagepath=null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);

    nama = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nama_barang);
    harga = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.harga_barang);
    kondisi = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.kondisi_barang);
    notelepon = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.no_telepon);

    uploadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
    messageText  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageText);
    btnselectpic = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_selectpic);
    imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_pic);


    btnselectpic.setOnClickListener(this);
    uploadButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    upLoadServerUri = "http://192.168.43.226/jualan/barang_tes/UploadToServer.php";
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds options to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    if(arg0==btnselectpic)
    {
        final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery","Cancel" };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (options[item].equals("Take Photo"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                    imagepath = f.getAbsolutePath();
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                }
                else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery"))
                {

                    Intent intent = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
                } else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();


    }
    else if (arg0==uploadButton) {

         dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);
         messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
         new Thread(new Runnable() {

             public void run() {

                  uploadFile(imagepath);
                  //send();

             }
           }).start();     
    }

}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {

            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
            for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                    f = temp;
                    break;
                }
            }
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap;
                BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                        bitmapOptions);

                // bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 70, 70, true);
                imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


                String path = android.os.Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator
                        + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                f.delete();
                OutputStream outFile = null;
                File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                try {
                    outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                    outFile.flush();
                    outFile.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == 2) {

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            imagepath = getPath(selectedImage);
            String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePath, null, null, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
            String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
            c.close();
            Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            //Log.w("path of image from gallery......******************.........", picturePath+"");
            imageview.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            messageText.setText("Uploading file path:" +imagepath);
        }
    }
}

/*  if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getData().getPath(); 

        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        imagepath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
        Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
        imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        messageText.setText("Uploading file path:" +imagepath);

    } */
     public String getPath(Uri uri) {
            String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }


public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

      String fileName = sourceFileUri;

      HttpURLConnection conn = null;
      DataOutputStream dos = null;  
      String lineEnd = "\r\n";
      String twoHyphens = "--";
      String boundary = "*****";
      int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
      byte[] buffer;
      int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
      File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

      if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

           dialog.dismiss(); 

           Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"+imagepath);

           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                   messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"+ imagepath);
               }
           }); 

           return 0;

      }
      else
      {
           try { 

                 // open a URL connection to the Servlet
               FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
               URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
               String nm = nama.getText().toString();
               String hrg = harga.getText().toString();
               String knds = kondisi.getText().toString();
               String notlp = notelepon.getText().toString();
               // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
               conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
               conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
               conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
               conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
               conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
               conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
               conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);
               conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_nama", nm);
               conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_harga", hrg);
               conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_kondisi", knds);
               conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_notelepon", notlp);

               dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=uploaded_nama" + lineEnd); // name=uploaded_nama so you have to get PHP side using mobile_no
               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes(nm); // nm is String variable
               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=uploaded_harga" + lineEnd); // name=uploaded_nama so you have to get PHP side using mobile_no
               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes(hrg); // nm is String variable
               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=uploaded_kondisi" + lineEnd); // name=uploaded_nama so you have to get PHP side using mobile_no
               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes(knds); // nm is String variable
               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=uploaded_notelepon" + lineEnd); // name=uploaded_nama so you have to get PHP side using mobile_no
               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes(notlp); // nm is String variable
               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
               dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                                         + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);


               // create a buffer of  maximum size
               bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

               bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
               buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

               // read file and write it into form...
               bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

               while (bytesRead > 0) {

                 dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                 bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                 bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                 bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                }

               // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

               // Responses from the server (code and message)
               serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
               String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

               Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " 
                       + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

               if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                  +" C:/AppServ/www/kambing/uploads";
                            messageText.setText(msg);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,InputInfo.class);
                            finish();
                            //startActivity(i); 
                        }
                    });                
               }    

               //close the streams //
               fileInputStream.close();
               dos.flush();
               dos.close();

          }

           catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

              dialog.dismiss();  
              ex.printStackTrace();

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });

              Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
          } catch (Exception e) {

              dialog.dismiss();  
              e.printStackTrace();

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });
              Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "  + e.getMessage(), e);  
          }
          dialog.dismiss();       
          return serverResponseCode; 

       } // End else block 
     }


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                             //String mydate = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

                             String TimeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMDdd_HHmmss",Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
                             String ImageFile = "JPEG_" + TimeStamp + "_";

                             File StorageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
                             new File(StorageDir + "/photofolder").mkdirs();
                             File outputfile=new File(StorageDir+"/photofolder/", ImageFile);

                             mCurrentPhotoPath = outputfile.getAbsolutePath();




                             return outputfile;

                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

add in your Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**As you want to implement it in your code here is it below**

First make a method in your class

```
 public void createFolder()
      {
          // here PictureFolder is the folder name you can change it offcourse
          String RootDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                  + File.separator + "PictureFolder";
          File RootFile = new File(RootDir);
          RootFile.mkdir();
      }
```

then in your code on Activity Result method which is

```
 if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
       .......
        }
```

change this to this

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
            if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) { 

                // create folder first
                createFolder();

                // get the photo from intent
                Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 

                // set the bitmap to imageview
                imageview.setImageBitmap(photo);

                // this code is use to generate random number and add to file
                // name so that each file should be different 
                Random generator = new Random();
                int n = 10000;
                n = generator.nextInt(n);
                String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";

                // set the file path
                // sdcard/PictureFolder/ is the folder created in create folder method
                String filePath = "/sdcard/PictureFolder/"+fname;

                // the rest of the code is for saving the file to filepath mentioned above
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
                try {
                    fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);

                //choose another format if PNG doesn't suit you
                photo.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);

                try {
                    bos.flush();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    bos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }  else if (requestCode == 2) {.........
```

i have tested this code on my phone and it work good